# How can i give a widget initial size in pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

i want give a widget an initial size >>>>>> not fixed , not minimum , and not maximum size

because i want the user be able to control the size of the widget, when i am using splitter.

how ?

look at this image :

[image]

i want the right side (the red) width to be 150 when i open the program > but when i try to change the size of it i want it to respond and to be changeable even if i want it to be bigger or smaller.

when i set a fixed size i will not be able to change its size.

when i set a minimum size it will expand and make the left side (the green) small.

when i set a maximam size i will be able to make it smaller but not bigger.

this is my code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.resize(800,500)
window_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()



first_widget = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
first_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(0,150,0)")



second_widget = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
second_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(150,0,0)")



splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter()
splitter.addWidget(first_widget)
splitter.addWidget(second_widget)


window_layout.addWidget(splitter)
window.setLayout(window_layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

when i tried the solution below i got a new error that the spacers are disabled are not working.

this is a code to explain the new problem

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.resize(800,500)
window_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()



first_widget = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
first_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(0,150,0)")
first_widget_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

first_widget_spacer_0 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(100000,0,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

first_widget_layout.addItem(first_widget_spacer_0)
first_widget.setLayout(first_widget_layout)




second_widget = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()
second_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(150,0,0)")



splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter()
splitter.addWidget(first_widget)
splitter.addWidget(second_widget)


splitter.setSizes([window.width() - 150, 150])


window_layout.addWidget(splitter)
window.setLayout(window_layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: When you have a new problem you should post a new question.

Comment: @Alexander but it is under the same problem , probably stackoverflow will close the new question. thanks for your time Alexander

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a `QSplitter`, you can simply use the `setSizes` method in order to adjust the sizes of each window controlled by the splitter.

Calling `window_layout.activate()` before will also ensure that it renders the proper sizes.  Otherwise it will be a scaled approximation based on the default window size of 640x480.

For example:

```
window_layout.activate()
splitter.setSizes([splitter.width() - 150,150])
```

From the Qt docs

> #### [`QSplitter.setSizes`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsplitter.html#setSizes)
>
> Sets the child widgets' respective sizes to the values given in the list.
>
> If the splitter is horizontal, the values set the width of each widget in pixels, from left to right. If the splitter is vertical, the height of each widget is set, from top to bottom.
>
> Extra values in the list are ignored. If list contains too few values, the result is undefined, but the program will still be well-behaved.
>
> The overall size of the splitter widget is not affected. Instead, any additional/missing space is distributed amongst the widgets according to the relative weight of the sizes.
>
> If you specify a size of 0, the widget will be invisible. The size policies of the widgets are preserved. That is, a value smaller than the minimal size hint of the respective widget will be replaced by the value of the hint.

An alternative method to set the initial size of a widget which is a little more versatile is to subclass the widget and define a `sizeHint` method that returns the desired `QSize`

Comment: thank you so much ..... but in this case i have to know how much of width is the window and write the size for each widget ..... Yes i can deal with it by a code and measure the current size and give the left side the width 150, and give the right side the rest .......................... but is there a way better than that ?

Comment: @Pythoner-sh  See my edit.  If that doesn't work for you then I would next recommend the alternative approach i mention at the bottom of my answer

Comment: i tried your solusion but i find that it disables the spacers.

Comment: @Pythoner-sh what do you mean by "it disables the spacers"? What spacers?

Comment: @Alexander remember that widget sizes are *never* correct until their layouts have been properly activated (unless size restraints have been specifically set using setMinimum/Maximum/Fixed functions); by default, widgets created without parents always have a default size of 640x480, and, in fact, that is what happens with your case, since the second widget is actually about 180 pixels wide, which is the correct proportion of 150:640 to the final 800 width (800x150/640). A possible solution is to call `window_layout.activate()` *after* setting the layout but *before* calling `setSizes()`.

Comment: @musicamante  i am not working on the example above it is for test >> in my project i have spacers to make the left side expand and press the right side to right >> when i did the solution above it disabled the spacers now the spacer does not press the right side to right.... i wrote a new code acts like the problem.